# search query from 2 dates and 2 time

Tags: ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I have 4 Datetimepicker. the 2 datetimepicker is on dateformat(datefrom,dateto) and the other 2 datetimepicker is on Timeformat(timefrom,timeto).
I want to search a table that display only in datagridview that will display only start on Date from and time from to date to and time to... But my code doenst work.

here's my code:

```
Dim fromto As String = String.Empty
    fromto &= "Select * from setplan where endplan >='" & dtimefrom.Text & "'and endplan >='" & dtimeto.Text & "' and [Dateinput] >='" & ddatefrom.Text & "' and [dateinput] <= '" & ddateto.Text & "'"

    Dim connection As String = ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\planning.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection)
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(fromto)
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = fromto
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)

                If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                End If



                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try


        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need formatted string expressions for your date/time values:

```
fromto &= "Select * from setplan where endplan >= #" & ddateto.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & " " & dtimeto.Value.ToString("HH':'mm") & "# and [dateinput] >= #" & ddatefrom.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & " " & dtimefrom.Value.ToString("HH':'mm") & "#"
```